# The exact value of the norm of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces

I'm able to find the minimum and maximum values for the norm of the sum of two vectors using the triangle inequality, but I'm not sure if I can find the exact value without knowing the angle between the vectors.

The following information is given: $\quad\bar v , \bar w \in \Bbb R^n, \quad \Vert \bar v \Vert =2, \quad \Vert \bar w \Vert =3, \quad \bar v \cdot \bar w =-1$ (dot product).

Find $\Vert \bar v + 2\bar w \Vert$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try writing $\|\vec{v} + 2\vec{w}\|^2$ as $(\vec{v} + 2\vec{w}) \cdot (\vec{v} + 2\vec{w})$ and expand.

Comment: I got it now, thank you!

Comment: Great! You should write an answer and accept it (which is totally allowed).